# Excluding Figure Captions from List of Figures in tufte-book

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, tufte-book

I'm working with a `tufte-book` document in LaTeX and encountering a problem where I want to exclude the caption of a particular figure from being listed in the List of Figures (LoF). However, despite using the `\caption[]{}` command, the caption still appears in the LoF. Here's a minimal example of what I tried:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption[]{My caption 1} % Do not expect this caption to appear in the LoF
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \caption{My caption 2} % Expect this caption to appear in the LoF
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Is there a specific way to properly handle this exclusion within the `tufte-book` document class, or a workaround that does not involve manually editing the LoF?

Comment: With standard classes, such as article, you can use the `\caption*` command from the `caption` package (typeset the caption without entry in the list of tables and without label).
But I don't know if this works with tuft-book. See maybe: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550798/caption-in-tufte-book-behaves-differently-for-marginfigures-than-for-main-figur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporary prevent writing caption content to the list of figures  by redefining `\caption@addcontentsline`. This must be done between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to handle the '@' symbol in macro name, and in a group (`\begingroup`...`\endgroup`) to restore after that the normal command definition. Note that the figure number must be incremented by hand (with `\refstepcounter{figure}` outside the group).

```tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\caption@addcontentsline}[2]{}
  \makeatother
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{My caption 1} % Do not expect this caption to appear in the LoF
  \end{figure}
\endgroup
\refstepcounter{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \caption{My caption 2} % Expect this caption to appear in the LoF
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

To use this many times, define a new environment, for example `figurenolof` :

````tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurenolof}{%
\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\caption@addcontentsline}[2]{}
  \begin{figure}
  }{%
  \end{figure}
\endgroup
\refstepcounter{figure}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figurenolof}
  \caption{My caption 1} % Do not expect this caption to appear in the LoF
\end{figurenolof}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \caption{My caption 2} % Expect this caption to appear in the LoF
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```## Heading ##
````

Comment: Since I only want to exclude figures in case of ```ContinuedFloat```, I removed the modification of ```\refstepcounter{figure}```. Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tuft class has its own `\caption` and probably resets it in every figure environment (`\AtBeginDocument` doesn't help),  Note also that the default `\caption@caption` centers the caption.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\let\Caption=\caption@caption% caption package \caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \Caption[]{My caption 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \Caption{My caption 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also removes the figure number (which I want to keep) and is not compatible with ContinuedFloat.

Comment: So you really want two figure 1s?  Not a problem.